# How do I show variable names and descriptions in my Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx to document my Python project. This shows me all the methods of the project, but not any variable. I want to be able to list all variables too.

My code.rst is -

```
Code Documentation
=====================
.. automodule:: sql_fn
   :members:
```

Currently, my python project goes like this-

```
#test variable
var=0
test_fn():
    '''test function'''
    print "hello world"
```

How do I change code.rst or my project to show my `var` and it's description `test variable` also?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question-

To document a variable, the comment preceding it must start with a `#:` instead of just a  `#`. Sphinx then recognizes it as a comment for the upcoming variable.

```
#:test variable
var=0
test_fn():
    '''test function'''
    print "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to document the variables in the docstring of your function.  See [Google Style Python Docstrings](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/example_google.html).  If the variable is not in a function you should probably document it in the containing module's docstring.